# Help in identifying the pop up notification icon

Tags: applications, notification-icons

Can anyone please help me figure out the icon provided by me in the screenshot that appears on the top left corner of the notification bar which looks like a message box with an exclamation mark! Whether it is an app notification icon or android system based icon.

> [image: Top-left corner]

Comment: Pull down the notification bar to see which is the app responsible for this

Comment: Being on the left side it is an app icon and not system icon

Comment: This looks like a mail client not able to send messages in outbox, due to poor  connection or wrong outgoing server settings. Review the settings and try resending the message again, it will disappear

Comment: Thank you guys for your promt replies, @xavier_fakerat Yes that was an issue with my mail client, however somehow the name of the 3rd party mail app wasn't showing initially. I had to manually search 3 of my apps and check for then unsent item that was pending showing 62 days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pull down the notification bar, tap and hold on the notification and then tap "**i**" to show more information about the app that pushed the notification.

Comment: Thanks for your advise, was an issue with my mail client. However the notification icon wasn't showing any details but rather stayed static with that icon, even when I tried to swipe it off to clear. Thanks anyways.